# Function inside a function not working

Tags: c, function, random

I have a function to generate random number in C. It works fine when I call it in main() function. But when I try to call it inside another function definition it is returning same number again and again. Please help. I am unable to understand the reason for this.

```
double uniform_deviate ( int seed )
{
return seed * ( 1.0 / ( RAND_MAX + 1.0 ) );
}

int rand_range(int min_n, int max_n)
{
return  min_n + uniform_deviate ( rand() ) * ( max_n - min_n );
}

int rand_slot(int num_values)
{
int x;
x=rand_range(0,num_values);
return x;

 } 

 void main()
 {
   int x,y; 
    x=rand_range(0,10) - 'works fine'
    y=rand_slot(6) - 'gives 5 as the output repeatedly' 
  }
```

Comment: We would be better equipped to answer if you would include the definition of your function, and some examples of it working and not working. Anyone who could answer this question would be capable of writing a correct random function, and so would not repeat your mistake when guessing at your implementation.

Comment: I have included my code. please go through it

Comment: Firstly, what does "repeatedly" mean? Your code calls it only *once*. Where did "repeatedly" come from? Secondly, your code does not perform any output. So, what "output" are you talking about? How do you inspect `x` and `y`?

Comment: include the value for RAND_MAX and the outputs you are getting for x and y

Comment: yeah repeatedly means every time I run the code. As it is randomised it must give random output every time

Comment: You're using the same seed for `rand()` on each start (check out [srand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/)).

Comment: @Sourav Mandal: *Both* `x` and `y` will contain the same pair of values every time you run the code, because `rand()`'s seed value is never changed (you have to use `srand` for that). But you claim that the first call "works fine" while the second one does not "work fine". What is that supposed to mean? Again, both calls produce the same values each time the code is run, yet you are happy with the first one and unhappy with the second one. Why? What's the difference?

Comment: that is the problem, both calls are not giving the same output as they must

Comment: seed cannot be the problem as that would have caused both the outputs to be same on each run

Comment: @Sourav Mandal: Sorry, I can't make sense of what you are saying. Your calls must typically produce a pair of values `x` and `y`. (They most likely will be different.) However, you will get the same `x`-and-`y` pair each time you run the code. This is how it is supposed to work and this is how it works. E.g. in ideone your code always generates `8` and `2`. That's perfectly normal behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As the following test program shows, both your functions work just fine, except you always use the same randome seed, so everytime you run this program, it will give you the same result. You could remove the comment mark before `srand()` to fix this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

double uniform_deviate ( int seed )
{
    return seed * ( 1.0 / ( RAND_MAX + 1.0 ) );
}

int rand_range(int min_n, int max_n)
{
    return  min_n + uniform_deviate ( rand() ) * ( max_n - min_n );
}

int rand_slot(int num_values)
{
    int x;
    x=rand_range(0,num_values);
    return x;

} 

int main()
{
    int x,y,i; 

    //srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        x=rand_range(0,10);
        y=rand_slot(10);
        printf("i = %d : %d %d\n", i, x, y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Run result:

```
$ ./a.out 
i = 0 : 8 3
i = 1 : 7 7
i = 2 : 9 1
i = 3 : 3 7
i = 4 : 2 5
i = 5 : 4 6
i = 6 : 3 5
i = 7 : 9 9
i = 8 : 6 7
i = 9 : 1 6
```

---

This test program could be used to show that those two functions will give the same number list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

double uniform_deviate ( int seed )
{
    return seed * ( 1.0 / ( RAND_MAX + 1.0 ) );
}

int rand_range(int min_n, int max_n)
{
    return  min_n + uniform_deviate ( rand() ) * ( max_n - min_n );
}

int rand_slot(int num_values)
{
    int x;
    x=rand_range(0,num_values);
    return x;

} 

int main()
{
    int x,i;

    srand(1);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        x=rand_range(0,10);
        printf("i = %d : %d\n", i, x);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    srand(1);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        x=rand_slot(10);
        printf("i = %d : %d\n", i, x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Run result:

```
$ ./a.out 
i = 0 : 8
i = 1 : 3
i = 2 : 7
i = 3 : 7
i = 4 : 9
i = 5 : 1
i = 6 : 3
i = 7 : 7
i = 8 : 2
i = 9 : 5


i = 0 : 8
i = 1 : 3
i = 2 : 7
i = 3 : 7
i = 4 : 9
i = 5 : 1
i = 6 : 3
i = 7 : 7
i = 8 : 2
i = 9 : 5
```

Comment: I know this in crazy but I am still getting same no on each run using rand_slot, but random nos using rand_range, I am using Visual C. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @SouravMandal Did you copy and paste my test program?

Comment: Then I am no idea. I tested it by GCC 4.7.2 on Linux.

Comment: if seeding is done inside the rand_slot does it change anything?

Comment: @SouravMandal Oh, that could explain the phenomenon that you observed.